# Why is covariance not allowed with an abstract class?

Tags: c++, interface, abstract-class, covariance

```
class GameObject {
public:
    virtual ~GameObject() {}
};

class Player: public GameObject {};

struct IGameController {
    virtual GameObject* GetPlayer() = 0;
};

class CameraOnlyController : public IGameController {
public:
    GameObject* GetPlayer() override { return nullptr; }
};

class PlayerController : public IGameController {
public:
    PlayerController() { player = new Player(); }
    ~PlayerController() { delete player; }
    Player* GetPlayer() override { return player; }
private:
    Player* player;
};

int main() {
    IGameController* playerController = new PlayerController();
    Player* player = playerController->GetPlayer();     // error: a value of type "GameObject *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "Player *"
    delete playerController;
}
```

It does compile if I change the controller interface to PlayerController specifically

```
PlayerController* playerController = new PlayerController();
```

I understand playerController could point to a CameraOnlyController later on like so

```
playerController = new CameraOnlyController();
```

but since it does not when Player* player is initialized, why is this prevented?
Is it the compiler trying to enforce type safety, and I am assuming it knows that playerController was assigned to new PlayerController() at the time, but it's wrong to assume this?

Comment: `playerController` is of type `IGameController*`, and `IGameController::GetPlayer` returns `GameObject*`, not `Player*`. For all the compiler knows, `playerController` may point to `CameraOnlyController` or some other class derived from `IGameController`

Comment: `playerController` is an `IGameController*`.  As far as is known at compile time, that means `playerController->GetPlayer()` is a `GameObject*`. Yes, it happens to be the case that the specific value of `playerController` is such that the `GameObject*` it returns is also a valid `Player*`, but there's no way for the compiler to know this just from looking at the definitions of `IGameController`, `Player`, and `GameObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IGameController* playerController = new PlayerController();
```

`playerController` is of type `IGameController*`.

The C++ compiler type checking does **not** remember anything else about `playerController`.  It forgets the fact it was constructed from a pointer to `PlayerController`.

```
Player* player = playerController->GetPlayer();
```

so here it takes the information it is permitted to know, that `playerController` is a `IGameController*`, and states there is a type mismatch.

If you want the compiler to know more about the type of `playerController` you have to change the **type** of `playerController` yourself.  The C++ compiler will not automatically extend the type of `playerController` to be everything it could know when determining the meaning of the line of code.

At the same time, the C++ compiler is free to follow the as-if rule, and devirtualize the type of `playerController`.  But they may only do this *as-if* they didn't (for example, making your code faster).

Programming languages exist that permit more extensive type deduction of a given variable.  C++ is not one of them.

You can do this:

```
auto* playerController = new PlayerController();
auto* player = playerController->GetPlayer();
delete playerController;
```

in which case, the exact types of the various variables will be used, or

```
auto* playerController = new PlayerController();
Player* player = playerController->GetPlayer();
delete playerController;
```

which validates that `player` is of the type you want.